# How to generate all possible matrices given a number n in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I want to generate a list given a number n which returns all possible combinations from one to `n` recursively and without imports.

For example

```
generate 3
```

should return:

```
[[1,1,1],[1,1,2],[1,1,3],[1,2,1],[1,2,2],[1,2,3],[1,3,1],[1,3,2],[1,3,3],[2,1,1],[2,1,2],[2,1,3],[2,2,1],[2,2,2],[2,2,3],[2,3,1],[2,3,2],[2,3,3],[3,1,1],[3,1,2],[3,1,3],[3,2,1],[3,2,2],[3,2,3],[3,3,1],[3,3,2],[3,3,3]]
```

Logically something like this, which obviously returns an error:

```
generate n = [replicate n _ | _ <- [1..n]]
```

Comment: What is not working with *your* attempt?

Comment: I get the following error when declaring: generate n = [replicate n _ | _ <-[1..n]] 

<interactive>:63:27: error:
    • Found hole: _ :: a
      Where: ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
               the inferred type of generate :: Int -> [[a]]
               at <interactive>:63:1-41
    • In the second argument of ‘replicate’, namely ‘_’
      In the expression: replicate n _
      In the expression: [replicate n _ | _ <- [1 .. n]]
    • Relevant bindings include
        n :: Int (bound at <interactive>:63:10)
        generate :: Int -> [[a]] (bound at <interactive>:63:1)

Comment: Any reason why my question gets downvoted so much? Its a genuine question lol

Answer (score 1):

You can work with [**`replicateM :: Int -> m a -> m [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.19.1.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:replicateM):

```
import Control.Monad(replicateM)

generate :: Int -> [[Int]]
generate = replicateM <*> enumFromTo 1
```

The `replicateM` essentially works as:

```
(\x1 x2 … xn -> [x1, x2, …, xn]) <$> fx <*> fx <*> … <*> fx
```

where we repeat `fx` *n* times. Here we use `[1 .. n]`, so that means we pick an element from `[1 .. n]`, then another one for `[1 .. n]` and so on, until we picked `n` elements, and then combine these.

Comment: Nice! Is there a solution without imports?

Comment: @Coder Sure, implement `replicateM` yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Here my solution without imports:

`generate n = sequence (replicate n [1..n])`